# Handling a lightbox with doesn't have a close button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, lightbox

I have a simple lightbox but it doesn't have a close button, I need to know how can I close it using Selenium webdriver. Either I need to press ESCAPE key or click outside the lightbox to get rid of it. I need to know how to handle this.

Comment: What language bindings?

Comment: Java selenium..